Command for a comma-separated list of 'Nchoose' numbers from '1,2,...,Nmax' numbers
I found a code here from @John Kormylo that chooses \Nchoose numbers from 1,2,...,\Nmax numbers and give it out as comma-separatet \mylist.
Question: How could I make a command from this, like
\createlist{<name of list>}{<Nmax>}{<Nchoose>} 

For example \createliste{pokerlist}{52}{6}, so that I can say: 
Show list: \pokerlist 
or Third element is: \pgfmathparse{\pokerarray[2]} \pgfmathresult (see 'Hint') 
and so on.
Hint 1: I need it as an array too, but I think I can say \def\myarray{\mylist} then.
Hint 2: In these lists are no duplicates (For example "1,2,2,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" is NOT allowed.)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Choose \Ncoose from \Nmax
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nmax{52}% 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nchoose{12}% 


\begin{document}
% List of \Ncoose from \Nmax:
\foreach \i in {1,...,\Nmax} {\expandafter\xdef\csname index\i\endcsname{\i}}% create indexes
\foreach \i in {1,...,\Nmax} {% randomise (last step redundant)
  \pgfmathparse{random(\i,\Nmax)}%
  \let\j=\pgfmathresult
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempa\csname index\i\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempb\csname index\j\endcsname
  \global\expandafter\let\csname index\i\endcsname=\tempb
  \global\expandafter\let\csname index\j\endcsname=\tempa
}%
\xdef\mylist{\csname index1\endcsname}% create comma delimited list
\foreach \i in {2,...,\Nchoose} {\xdef\mylist{\mylist, \csname index\i\endcsname}}%


\section{{\Nchoose} random numbers from {1,2,\dots,\Nmax}}
\noindent\mylist

\section{{33} random numbers from {1,2,\dots,60}}
...

\section{{52} random numbers from {1,2,\dots,52}}
...
\end{document}


I don't think you need any package code for this, LaTeX has all the functionality pre-defined.

No duplicate answer based on a shuffled list
This makes a list 1..n then shuffles it and takes the first m entries
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn  \cs_set:Npn {Npe} % old latex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn  \clist_set:Nn {Ne} % old latex

\cs_new:Npn \cis_comma_tmp:n #1 {#1,}
\cs_new:Npn \cis_comma_tmpb:n #1 {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1} , }


\NewDocumentCommand\createlist{mmm}{
  \clist_set:Ne \l_tmpa_clist {
    \int_step_function:nN {#2} \cis_comma_tmp:n
  }
  
  \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_clist
  \seq_shuffle:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \cs_set:Npe#1 {
    \int_step_function:nN {#3-1} \cis_comma_tmpb:n
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#3}
  }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\createlist\aaa{52}{12}
\typeout{\aaa}


\createlist\bbb{60}{33}
\typeout{\bbb}


\createlist\ccc{52}{52}
\typeout{\ccc}


\end{document}

producing
12,21,36,23,2,24,3,49,25,52,8,10


9,15,36,27,51,48,10,32,55,31,49,57,47,5,42,12,29,43,17,56,44,34,35,30,2,16,41,23,28,33,37,11,59

36,34,15,49,7,45,33,31,2,29,51,50,5,10,44,17,6,43,3,14,1,19,9,23,48,24,7,32,42
,28,11,46,16,35,40,27,18,20,4,30,26,12,25,52,21,41,38,47,8,39,22,13



original answer
This produces the following terminal output (I left trailing , although they could be removed
40,12,45,51,43,15,6,21,8,37,16,39,


38,6,24,59,19,50,51,37,28,10,46,17,49,23,33,47,60,45,36,43,1,56,9,33,52,6,45,2,
30,2,30,49,46,


52,9,27,42,37,7,8,34,31,21,6,36,18,22,7,46,7,50,39,9,29,44,10,2,41,21,44,18,11,
20,37,16,16,36,16,26,49,7,21,18,21,40,32,28,43,31,27,25,5,18,16,6,

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\createlist{mmm}{
  \cs_set:Npe#1{\prg_replicate:nn{#3}{\int_rand:n{#2},}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\createlist\aaa{52}{12}
\typeout{\aaa}


\createlist\bbb{60}{33}
\typeout{\bbb}


\createlist\aaa{52}{52}
\typeout{\aaa}


\end{document}


This is assuming that duplicates are allowed.
If not then instead use \seq_suffle on a sequence 1...N and then take the first m items.

A version removing one , and declaring e versions for old latex
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn  \cs_set:Npn {Npe} % old latex
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\createlist{mmm}{
  \cs_set:Npe#1{\use:e{\exp_not:N\use_none:n\use:e{\prg_replicate:nn{#3}{,\int_rand:n{#2}}}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\createlist\aaa{52}{12}
\typeout{\aaa}


\createlist\bbb{60}{33}
\typeout{\bbb}


\createlist\aaa{52}{52}
\typeout{\aaa}


\end{document}


It's impressive to have that in one line; but for further work (TikZ, pgfplots etc.) it can be advantageous to have it in the usual form. The list of random numbers is of course just a detail of the whole thing and not the main goal.

@cis possibly although the result is in the same format used by a pgf foreach loop, just a comma separated list. So even if you use pgf elsewhere this could still be considered.

I get Undefined control sequence. \createlist code #1#2#3->\cs_set:Npe ... at mine and at 'overleaf'. And I think the last comma can become problematic.

@cis I added a version addressing both points

So, I think, I can use that.

Oh, I overread that: "This is assuming that duplicates are allowed."
Nonono.... For example "1,2,2,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" is NOT  allowed. In the startpost-code there were no duplicates produced.

@cis I can post a no duplicate version but I see nothing in the code in the question that removes duplicates, you just (as in this answer) call the random number geneartor n times???

I don't know, but I've worked with the John Kormylo version (starting post) many times and it doesn't produce duplicates. For example, if you enter 52 numbers and select 52 from them, you would have something like a shuffled deck of cards as a named list (\mylist).

@cis see update

Strange: in the new code I get ! Undefined control sequence. \createlist code #1#2#3->\clist_set:Ne                                         \l_tmpa_clist {\int_step_function:nN ... again.

@cis oh same issue as before you have an old latex, add \cs_generate_variant:Nn  \clist_set:Nn {Ne} % old latex  to define the e form.

If you don't want duplicates, you have two strategies, but the one suggested by David is slower by a very large factor. Here I show two strategies: in the first the sequence with the integers from 1 to Nmax is generated, then shuffled and the first Nmax items are stored in a new sequence; in the second implementation, a random integer from 1 to Nmax is generated and added to the sequence if not already present, the process stopping when Nmax items have been added.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3benchmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createlistA}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = Nmax, #3 = Nchoose
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } }
  \seq_shuffle:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_cis_list_#1_seq }
  \int_step_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:ce { l_cis_list_#1_seq } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\createlistB}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = Nmax, #3 = Nchoose
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \bool_until_do:nn { \int_compare_p:n { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq = #3 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \int_rand:n { #2 } }
    \seq_if_in:NVF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
   }
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_cis_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_eq:cN { l_cis_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_seq
 }

\benchmark:n { \createlistA{testA}{200}{6} }

\benchmark:n { \createlistB{testB}{200}{6} }

\stop

The output of the benchmark is
0.00248 seconds (1.66e4 ops)
7.69e-5 seconds (511 ops)

For Nmax=10 and Nchoose=6, we get
1.33e-4 seconds (869 ops)
8.36e-5 seconds (556 ops)

so the second strategy also wins when Nmax is small.
Hence I'll go with the second strategy.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = Nmax, #3 = Nchoose
  \cis_createlist:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listitem}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = item number
  \seq_item:cn { l_cis_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { l_cis_list_#1_seq } { ,~ }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq
\tl_new:N \l__cis_createlist_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cis_createlist:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq
  \bool_until_do:nn
   {
    \int_compare_p:nNn { \seq_count:N \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq } = { #3 }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Ne \l__cis_createlist_tmp_tl { \int_rand:n { #2 } }
    \seq_if_in:NVF \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq \l__cis_createlist_tmp_tl
     {
      \seq_put_right:NV \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq \l__cis_createlist_tmp_tl
     }
   }
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_cis_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_eq:cN { l_cis_list_#1_seq } \l__cis_createlist_tmp_seq
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\Nmax}{52}
\newcommand{\Nchoose}{12}

\begin{document}

\section{{\Nchoose} random numbers from \{1,2,\dots,\Nmax\}}
\createlist{first}{\Nmax}{\Nchoose}

\printlist{first}

\section{33 random numbers from \{1,2,\dots,60\}}
\createlist{second}{60}{33}

\printlist{second}

\section{52 random numbers from \{1,2,\dots,52\}}
\createlist{third}{52}{52}

\printlist{third}

\end{document}

If you need this to work also with TeX Live 2020, 2021 or 2022, add
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }

after \ExplSyntaxOn.
If you want to support also TeX Live 2018 or 2019, you must
\usepackage{xparse}



the second strategy has no guaranteed termination though

@DavidCarlisle Possibly. I could add a threshold for the attempts, say 1000 times Nmax.

TYVM too!   .............
